# How to save the html code of a website correctly?

Tags: html, web

I wan´t to download the html code of facebook, but when I open the file the page opens but without the graphic design. Any suggestions would be grat!

Comment: Facebook is not a traditional html website. It is a dynamically generated javascript application that can't be downloaded in the traditional sense.

Comment: Good to know.Thanks! How would you know if a website it´s a dynamically generated javascript application?

Comment: Try developer tools in chrome or F12 in IE , and copy the Elements. You will get the structure of the html. And check the source of stylesheet linked and download them. This will help you to improve what you have downloaded.